# Assign one JPPFTask to all nodes and compare results

Tags: java, grid, distributed, jppf

I am using the JPPF framework to execute tasks on distributed machines. Everything works as expected. Now I need to identify saboteurs among available nodes in the grid. Therefore I have to execute dedicated tasks one each nodes and compare the results. By definition the most frequent result is correct and deviating results indicate a saboteur.

Because a *Bundler instance is assigned to each nodes, I have to manipulate the JPPFDriver in some way. Any idea, how I should do that?

My Setup:

- JPPF framework v4.0
- Java 1.7 (32bit)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Disclaimer: I'm the JPPF project founder and main developer.

I can think of several possibilities to achieve this:

1) You can use a [broadcast job](http://www.jppf.org/doc/v4/index.php?title=Job_Service_Level_Agreement#Broadcast_jobs), a job with a single task which will be replicated and distributed to all the nodes. Since this type of job does not return any results, you could make the task send a JMX notification with the result and the node identification, or just send notifications for deviating nodes.

2) It could also make sense to implement a custom [node management MBean](http://www.jppf.org/doc/v4/index.php?title=Pluggable_MBeans) for checking for saboteurs, especially since you can automatically [forward management requests](http://www.jppf.org/doc/v4/index.php?title=Nodes_management_and_monitoring_via_the_driver) to all connected nodes. This approach has the advantage that it won't interfere with the "normal" grid processing flow.